# Difference in differences when pre and post outcomes are different variables

Tags: inference, causality, difference-in-difference

Diff in diff question:

Can you do difference in differences if the pre-treatment outcome is a different measure to the post-treatment outcome?

For example, in Education, imagine there is a new programme that occurs in eighth grade and is rolled out to some areas/schools. If you want to use attainment as the outcome variable, you won't have the same measure pre and post for each student. I.e., pre treatment, attainment might be 7th grade test scores. However, the post treatment attainment measure might be 9th grade test scores, which is different to the 7th grade test scores!

Is difference in difference even appropriate here? Do we have to aggregate to a certain geography (like schools)?

Could we use a relative performance measure (like percentile performance in test)? Seems promising, but then parallel trends surely won't hold because the performance of your treated group affects the relative performance of the control group mechanically....

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In your example of test scores, these variables might be similar enough to consider as the same. The specific course work will change, naturally. But you could map categorically (math, science, etc.) Using A,B,…F as categorical outcomes or percentages should work. I would avoid percentiles as you noted because this would introduce dependence.

DiD models can allow for imbalance in the pre-treatment variable, but there’s an assumption that both group means are changing at the same linear rate. (No change is fine, too.)

In example, suppose that control group test scores were already shifting, from C average to B average. And in treatment group, the average score was D. DiD parallel trends assumption would believe that over the same interval, treatment group means would increase to C average in the absence of any treatment (counter factual.) so the effect, if present, would be realized by an even bigger movement in the treatment group mean (B average or A average, for example.)

You could also consider using grade point average as opposed to test scores from a specific course. Since this metric takes all coursework into account, it should be robust against situations like “these students took chemistry for the first time, which was categorically different from any previous coursework, unlike algebra 2 which was categorically similar to algebra 1”

Comment: Thanks! And what about if the post treatment outcome is something that cannot be observed pre treatment (i.e., makes it to the end of high school)? Presumably you can't do difference in differences here and would need to use another method (like IV or PSM matching)?

Comment: Your question goes beyond my expertise here, but I agree with your assessment, DiD would not be suitable in this case. However, an instrument variable might be possible.